# Preserve variables set within userscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, userscripts

I am writing a script in tampermonkey.

I have an `var arr  = ["alex", "felix"]` which can be updated according to the usage of script. When there is a change I added the value to the arr as; `arr.push("kelix")`

But when the script is reloaded, the arr is still `var arr  = ["alex", "felix"]`. The newValue is not pushed to the array. So how can I preserve the changes in the variable `arr`?

What should I do?

Comment: Use localStorage/sessionStorage to store variables to reuse after refresh.`sessionStorage.setItem('arr',arr):` and retrieve it using `sessionStorage.getItem('arr');`. More information on sessionStorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: you can use `localStorage.arr` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `localStorage`. Below see example script that will allow you to change document title and will remember it over reloading:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remember value
// @namespace   util
// @description Test that remembers any saved value after reload
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
// Try to load saved data from local storage
const FIELD_NAME = "userscript_TEST";
var saved = localStorage[FIELD_NAME]?JSON.parse(localStorage[FIELD_NAME]):{};

// Save data when leaving tab
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
    localStorage[FIELD_NAME] = JSON.stringify(saved);
});
// This changed document title and remembers it
window.changeDocumentTitleForever = function(title) {
    saved["title"] = title;
    document.title = title;
}

// This loads title after loading page
if(saved.title)
    document.title = saved.title;
```

Usage in console:

```
changeDocumentTitleForever("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing userscript, `GM_setValue`, `GM_getValue` may be a better choice than `localStorage`.

```
var arr = ["alex", "felix"];
try { arr = JSON.parse(GM_getValue('arr', '["alex", "felix"]')); }
catch (_ignore) { /* ignore when JSON.parse fail */ }
// do something with arr
arr.push('kelix');
GM_setValue('arr', JSON.stringify(arr));
```